# How do we implement comments in TypeScript so intellisense sees them

Tags: comments

We just love TypeScript. It makes our lives much easier. I especially like the intellisense part empowered by Web Essentials.

I'm not shure about how to implement this correctly.

We use comments like:

```
/** This function returns the current user */
```

It shows up perfectly when typing in a TypeScript file that references the .ts file that declares the comment.

But the comment for the 'maintainSelection' option does not show up

```
/** CttGrid options */
export interface CttGridOptions extends kendo.ui.GridOptions
{
    /** true - Rows scrolled out of view are maintained */
    maintainSelection: boolean;
}
```

...

```
var activiteitenInGrid : kendoWrappers.CttGrid = $('#werkpakketActiviteitenInGrid').kendoCttGrid
({
    navigatable: true,
    pageable: false,
    sortable: true,
    groupable: true,
    resizable: true,
    filterable: true,
    selectable: 'multiple',
    maintainSelection: true,
    scrollable: {
    virtual: true
    },
    editable: "incell",
    columns: activiteitenColumns
}).data('kendoCttGrid');
```

Now when I hover my mouse over the 'maintainSelection' option it says it's a boolean but the comment does not show up. So it recognizes the options from the interface description but forgets the comment. Is there a way to make those comments show up in intellisense too?

Regards
Paul

Answer (score 1):

This isn't a solution to the problem but it does help a bit.

In Visual Studio Code while hovering over a function, if you hold down `Ctrl` on Windows or ⌘ on Mac it will cause the preview window to show some of the function you might jump to. This effectively shows the first few comments in the function.

Answer (score 1):

[This article explains it well](https://dev.to/sumansarkar/how-to-use-jsdoc-annotations-with-vscode-for-intellisense-7co)

Basically, something like this will work:

````js
/**
 * @description This function takes Moment objects and calculates
 * the difference between the two dates
 * @param {Moment} startDate
 * @param {Moment} endDate
 * @returns {number}
 */
const getDiff = (startDate, endDate) => startDate.diff(endDate, 'days');```
````

Answer (score 0):

There are main way to implement comments in tyscript in
1.using jsdocs comments
the recommended and  most widely used approach ..
It uses special tags like @param, @returns, and @description to provide information about functions, variables, classes, and other entities.

2.Using single-line // comments
While not as powerful as JSDoc, single-line comments can also be used for basic documentation that IntelliSense can pick up.